PlatformException: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check values.xml
I am encountering an issue after installing Firebase packages in my Flutter project. When I try to run the app, I receive the following error message:
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2193 in debug mode...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/e.firebase_tut(11200): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=1332 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=5000
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:54646/H15QNa44N74=/ws
I/e.firebase_tut(11200): Compiler allocated 4670KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
E/flutter (11200): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly., Exception, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly.
E/flutter (11200):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.lambda$optionsFromResource$4$io-flutter-plugins-firebase-core-FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin(FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:207)
E/flutter (11200):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/flutter (11200):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/flutter (11200):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/flutter (11200):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/flutter (11200): , null)
E/flutter (11200): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:242:7)
E/flutter (11200): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11200): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter (11200): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11200): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter (11200): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11200): #3      main (package:firebase_tuto/main.dart:6:3)
E/flutter (11200): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11200):
Application finished.

Exited (-1).

